# bigquery table is empty when using pandas to_gbq

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I have some data in panda which i stored to bigquery using `to_gbq` api in pandas. I want to update couple of rows from the table. I loaded the data in pandas using `read_gbq` api & updated the data & when i write back using `to_gbq` it gives me empty table. Data is totally lost. I am unable to figure out whats wrong.

Any advice?

Comment: Wish I could help, but you at least helped me find out that there's a BQ module for Pandas. Thanks!

Comment: can you share with us your code? not sure if it's some flag forcing some table truncation happening