# 400 Error while reading data using pandas to_gbq to create a table in Google BigQuery

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query data from a MySQL server and write it to Google BigQuery using pandas .to_gbq api.

```
def production_to_gbq(table_name_prod,prefix,table_name_gbq,dataset,project):
    # Extract data from Production

    q = """
        SELECT *
        FROM
            {}
        """.format(table_name_prod)

    df = pd.read_sql(q, con)

    # Write to gbq    
    df.to_gbq(dataset + table_name_gbq, project, chunksize=1000, verbose=True, reauth=False, if_exists='replace', private_key=None)

    return df
```

I keep getting a 400 error indicating invalid input.

```
Load is 100.0% Complete
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadRequest                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in load_data(self, dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize, schema)
    569                     self.client, dataframe, dataset_id, table_id,
--> 570                     chunksize=chunksize):
    571                 self._print("\rLoad is {0}% Complete".format(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_gbq/_load.py in load_chunks(client, dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize, schema)
     73             destination_table,
---> 74             job_config=job_config).result()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py in result(self, timeout)
    527         # TODO: modify PollingFuture so it can pass a retry argument to done().
--> 528         return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)
    529 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py in result(self, timeout)
    110             # Pylint doesn't recognize that this is valid in this case.
--> 111             raise self._exception
    112 

BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 10; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

GenericGBQException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-ef9c7cec0104> in <module>()
----> 1 departments.to_gbq(dataset + table_name_gbq, project, chunksize=1000, verbose=True, reauth=False, if_exists='replace', private_key=None)
      2 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_gbq(self, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, verbose, reauth, if_exists, private_key)
   1058         return gbq.to_gbq(self, destination_table, project_id=project_id,
   1059                           chunksize=chunksize, verbose=verbose, reauth=reauth,
-> 1060                           if_exists=if_exists, private_key=private_key)
   1061 
   1062     @classmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, verbose, reauth, if_exists, private_key)
    107                       chunksize=chunksize,
    108                       verbose=verbose, reauth=reauth,
--> 109                       if_exists=if_exists, private_key=private_key)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in to_gbq(dataframe, destination_table, project_id, chunksize, verbose, reauth, if_exists, private_key, auth_local_webserver, table_schema)
    980     connector.load_data(
    981         dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize=chunksize,
--> 982         schema=table_schema)
    983 
    984 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in load_data(self, dataframe, dataset_id, table_id, chunksize, schema)
    572                     ((total_rows - remaining_rows) * 100) / total_rows))
    573         except self.http_error as ex:
--> 574             self.process_http_error(ex)
    575 
    576         self._print("\n")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py in process_http_error(ex)
    453         # <https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors>`__
    454 
--> 455         raise GenericGBQException("Reason: {0}".format(ex))
    456 
    457     def run_query(self, query, **kwargs):

GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 10; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details.
```

I've investigated the table schema,

```
id  INTEGER NULLABLE    
name    STRING  NULLABLE    
description STRING  NULLABLE    
created_at  INTEGER NULLABLE    
modified_at FLOAT   NULLABLE
```

and it is the same as the dataframe:

```
id                        int64
name                     object
description              object
created_at                int64
modified_at             float64
```

The table is created in GBQ but remains empty.

I read around a little but am not finding much on pandas.to_gbq api, except for this which seemed relevant but has no reply:

[bigquery table is empty when using pandas to_gbq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330783/bigquery-table-is-empty-when-using-pandas-to-gbq)

I found one potential solution about numbers in the object datatypes which are being passed into the GBQ table without quotes, something fixed by setting column datatypes as string.

[I use to_gbq on pandas for updating Google BigQuery and get GenericGBQException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191376/i-use-to-gbq-on-pandas-for-updating-google-bigquery-and-get-genericgbqexception)

I tried the fix:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtypes == object:
        df[col] = df[col].fillna('')
        df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
```

Unfortunately I still get the same error. Similarly trying to format missing data  and setting dtypes for int and float also gives the same error.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I would suggest to break down the steps to isolate the problem. For example, saving the dataframe (or a sample) to a csv and try to import it with the UI or try to write some control dataframes using `.to_gbq`

Answer (score 2):

Found that bigquery cannot properly handle **\r** (sometimes **\n** too)
Had the same issue, localized the problem and I was really surprised when just replacing **\r** with space fixed it:

```
for col in list(df.columns):
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.replace(u'\r', u' ') if isinstance(x, str) or isinstance(x, unicode) else x)
```

Comment: Had an issue with `unicode` so tried `bytes` instead, but unfortunately the fix didn't work for me.

Comment: @Echochi It should be string, but not bytes. I believe you need to use something like unicodedata.normalize if you have some unexpected symbols that crashing script.

Comment: @SirJ unfortunately for some reason trying `unicode.normalize` didn't work no matter the form I used. I ended up removing all special characters, though that mangles the text a little: `df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', x))`, but that worked.

Comment: @Echochi If it works `df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', x))`, then:

1. Just take a look on result bigquery table. How many items it has. By default in `to_gbq` chunk is 1000 items. So if table has only 20k from 1M so somewhere in between of 20k and 21k are "bad data".

2. Try to use this function for each column separately, to determine at list column with "bad" data. 

In this way you can detect what kind of data is crashing your script.

Answer (score 1):

I have ended up here several times when I've had a similar issue with importing to bigquery from parquet files on cloud storage. However, each time I've forgotten the way to solve it, so I hope it's not too much of a breach of protocol to leave my findings here!

What I realised was that I have columns that are all NULL, which will look like they have a data type in pandas, but if you use pyarrow.parquet.read_schema(parquet_file), you will see that the data type is null.

After removing the column, the upload will work!

Answer (score 1):

I had some invalid characters in `string` columns (`object` in `pandas`). I use @Echochi  approach and it worked

```
for col in list(parsed_data.select_dtypes(include='object').columns):
        parsed_data[col] = parsed_data[col].apply(lambda x:re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+','', str(x)))
```

It was a little bit to restrictive with the accepted characters, so I used a more general aproach, given that the biquery compatibility with `UTF-8` [bigquery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#string-type)

```
for col in list(parsed_data.select_dtypes(include='object').columns):
        parsed_data[col] = parsed_data[col].apply(lambda x:re.sub(r"[^\u0900-\u097F]+",,'?', str(x)))
```

with `r"[^\u0900-\u097F]+"` you will accept all `UTF-8` compatible charset

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue because of an unwanted column 'Unnamed 0' present in the dataset. I removed that and problem got solved. Try to see the shape and head, if any null column or unwanted column exists in the dataset

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).